# Onvif camera streaming and control in QT C++ or VC++

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, onvif

I am new to ONVIF camera and SOAP. I want to build an application that can stream and control PTZ ONVIF camera device. I used an application in C# and its working.

I want to use this in C++. I have tried to use some github codes but they have many problems related to some dependencies and libraries.

Can anyone provide some good resource which can be useful for me to start this task.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

The bet resource is the onvif website itself.
I recommend reading the [ONVIF Application Programmers Guide](https://www.onvif.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ONVIF_WG-APG-Application_Programmers_Guide-1.pdf?ccc393&ccc393).
Then you can find more details in [this](https://www.onvif.org/profiles/specifications/) page. (Documentations and WSDL files)

If you are not familiar with ONVIF better to read about it first and to understand the ONVIF profiles.

Note that:

1- you'll need to have a clear grasp of what XML and SOAP are. You would develop a XML parser (Suggestion: There are few libraries to parse XMLs. However I found them useless for me and have developed my own using boost library.)

2- You have to send and receive SOAP messages so write a good data transfer module. I used *libcurl* you can use boost library too.

Have fun coding.